# Postgres: DROP TABLE and ALTER TABLE hangs because of locks

Tags: postgresql

After issuing `DROP TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` command `pg_stat_activity` table becomes full of `Locks` and the query hangs forever. Killing `PID`s and reissuing query gives the same result. The problem disappears after the system gets restarted (I restart `docker` container for that).

How to investigate this issue?

Comment: Determine who is holding the locks on the table in question _before_ you attempt to drop it.

Comment: @mustaccio, I always see multiple locks of unknown nature in pg_stat_activity  table.  I can not give a better report at time, as I have just reset the docker container

Comment: You could try `lock the_table in exclusive mode nowait` before attempting the ALTER or DROP. That way you would get an error immediately if some other transaction still uses that table. Make sure you do that in a transaction to keep the lock if it succeeds.

Comment: Well, there you go. You'll need to figure out the source of those locks.

Comment: See if this helps [Database "frozen" on ALTER TABLE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132851/database-frozen-on-alter-table)

Comment: @mustaccio, how to apply this approch  `ALTER TABLE tblah ADD COLUMN cblah;
ALTER TABLE tblah ALTER COLUMN cblah DEFAULT dblah;
UPDATE tblah SET cblah = dblah WHERE cblah IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE tblah ALTER COLUM cblah NOT NULL; ` to queries like `drop table blah` or `alter table tblah drop column cblah`?